# Custom class to fieldset in Joomla module

Tags: css, joomla, content-management-system, fieldset

I am creating a new module and I need/want to add a custom CSS or ID to the entire fieldset, is it possible? How?

My code is:

```
<config>
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset  name="mymodule" >
```

What do I have to do to have a custom CSS?

Comment: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=629&t=598760a and this http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_custom_template_parameter_types

Comment: Sorry that I can do. I want it to add to the entire FIELDS a custom class and not to one specific field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in the default.php (your default view in tmpl) you call the fieldset, you can use whatever class you want to be applied to the fields. Ex to use in each row while you loop the fieldset:

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="details">
<?php foreach ($this->form->getFieldset('details') as $field): ?>
    <div class="control-group YOURCLASS_FIELDSET_HERE">
        <div class="control-label">
        <?php echo $field->label; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <?php echo $field->input; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't make my self clear. This will work fine in the tmpl/default.php as you mean. What I mean is when you open a Module in the Admin you have in the right side the drop-down with the module configuration. Well I want in this view to change a CSS or ID. I manage to do this via jQuery but that is not the right way. I wanted to know if there is any tag that I can add to the parameters.xml that would change this CLASS or ID.

Comment: Unfortunately or not, that is the right way - using jQuery, since the system calls the com_config to configure the modules and plugins based on the manifest file params. It reads the fieldset and renders the fields, which are the ones that can have the attribute class.

Comment: Nice :D Thanks for the feedback. Everything is working right now.